# How can I ask about generalization and formal arguing errors?

Tags: support

I was trying to discuss with a friend about some human behaviour.

He is always stating that each men is not robot and **every** generalization is false.

I think is that he is attacking my formal argumentative errors but proving that I'm not a great speaker is not showing his thesis is correct.

I think that there are many similarities among human beings. In fact saying that we have red blood or that manipulation techniques are effective with many human being is not a generalization.

Saying that every human being is unique is not proving that human being are completely different from the others. What he says sounds to me like: "we cannot know nothing because everyone is unique".

Can I state that his attacks are not formally correct?

Which would be the best way to ask the question?

Comment: Well for one thing, strip out the "Speaking of ..." paragraph as that's not a question. Then strip out the "In my opinion" paragraph ,which is just a personal philosophy. Then make the question about philosophy clearer.

Comment: @virmaior: thanks. I've corrected, if you have other suggestion I appreciate!

Comment: Another limitation looking at it is that you're hitting a hot button topic -- "the behaviour of women". it'd be easier for people to answer if you made the topic more generic. But a further difficulty is that the bits we're hearing of the argument wouldn't be enough to indicate whether it's fallacious (though the conclusion is pretty out there as it stands)

Comment: @virmaior: thanks for saying that the conclusion is good. Do you think I can try to ask the quesion or is better not? (I'm at risk of suspension due to not well received questions)

Comment: I think it'd be best to look at the sorts of questions that are well-received here (high votes on the question and the answer). One problem is that you might be using "philosophy" differently than the SE intends to. We're not here to help people resolve personal disputes and "identify the fallacy" is usually pretty uninteresting (both because most fallacies are informal and because it's something you should be able to do by abstracting away from your particular issue and using google).

Comment: thanks for the suggestion!